# Convert string to DateTime in c#

Tags: c#, string, datetime

What is the easiest way to convert the following date created using

```
dateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

into a proper `DateTime` object?

```
20090530123001
```

I have tried `Convert.ToDateTime(...)` but got a `FormatException`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If the string may not be in the correct format (and you wish to avoid an exception) you can use the `DateTime.TryParseExact` method like this:

```
DateTime dateTime;
DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "yyyyMMddHHmmss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
```

Comment: I think this does the same, not? Convert.ToDateTime(datetime, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Answer (score 4):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 3):

Good tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/String2DateTime.aspx) -- I think you just want [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(VS.71).aspx), or [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(VS.71).aspx) with the right format string!