# convert string to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

i want to convert this string into DateTime.

```
 Tue Aug 19 15:05:05 +0000 2008
```

I have tried the following code, but not getting the proper value.

```
string strDate = "Tue Aug 19 15:05:05 +0000 2008";
DateTime date;
DateTime.Parse(strDate,out date);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to DateTime in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592653/convert-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "Tue Aug 19 15:05:05 +0000 2008", 
    "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);
```

For more safety use [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) method:

```
string str = "Tue Aug 19 15:05:05 +0000 2008";
string format = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine(date.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Nicely formatted to show the correlation between the actual data and the date time info string.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) and [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx).

Comment: @Mark I was already doing that but not getting the proper values.

Comment: @Mark thats why i posted question on SO

Comment: Yes, I missed that when I first looked at your question, which is why I edited my answer to include `ParseExact`—but Darin's answer is much more comprehensive anyway.