# Convert DateTime Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

net 4 and c#.

I have in a Text Box DateTimeValue

```
3/1/2011 12:00:00 AM
```

I need to convert it in a String of this format:

```
Format="yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Any idea how to do it?
PS: I can remove information about the time

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) like so:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("3/1/2011 12:00:00 AM", "G", 
           CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Be sure to specify the culture, because the format you used is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

is this what are you asking for?

```
DateTime.Parse("3/1/2011 12:00:00 AM").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: see my comment. This is dangerous code, because it depends on the local settings of the user. Most of the other answers have the same problem, but yours was voted on as the only one, so I only downvoted yours.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to include the Namespace: System.Globalization in order to access CultureInfo.

eg: `using System.Globalization; // for CultureInfo`

Answer (score 0):

try this

Convert.ToDateTime(Text1.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-DD")

Comment: so, what's the `dt` and `ds` ?

Answer (score 0):

See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064038/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-in-net). Remember that the regional settings of the computer effect the way that the string is interpreted. With my region (danish), your date format will not translate using DateTime.Parse.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

There are several options, one example:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2011, 3, 1);
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

string dt = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();