# How to Convert this string "Tue Feb 22 00:00:00 UTC+0200 2011" to a DateTime?

Tags: c#

Anyone can help on this issue? i get this string value from Javascript in an ASP.NET Web Control and want to use it as DateTime value!

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to DateTime in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592653/convert-string-to-datetime-in-c)

Comment: Possible but if you would know the exact format string for this kind of date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var dateTimeObject = DateTime.ParseExact("Tue Feb 22 00:00:00 UTC+0200 2011", "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss UTCzzzzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.DateTime.ParseExact("Tue Feb 22 00:00:00 UTC+0200 2011", "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss \"UTC\"zzz yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

You can find the complete list of possible formats at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: I have voted but checked answer StackOverflowException because of first answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

trydoing this: DateTime.ParseExact