# Convert String to Date Time

Tags: vb.net, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert string to DateTime in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592653/convert-string-to-datetime-in-c)

I am trying to convert a string in the format "20110617111051" to date time.
Currently I am using String.SubString() function to extract year, month, day, time to format a standard string and then using Convert.ToDateTime(string). Is there any other simple way to do this?

```
Dim x as String="20110617110715"
Dim standard as string = x.SubString(0,4) & "-" & x.SubString(4,2) & "-" & x.SubString(6,2) 'and time
Dim dateTime as DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(standard)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact`.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

VB

```
Dim myDate as DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) function in conjunction with the exact format of your input string. Example:

C#:

```
string input = "20110617111051";
string format = "yyyyMMddhhmmss";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

VB:

```
Dim input As String = "20110617111051"
Dim format As String = "yyyyMMddhhmmss"
Dim dateTime as DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more info on custom date and time strings.