# Convert YYYYMMDD string date to a datetime value

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert string to DateTime in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592653/convert-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

A question

I got a string value that actually get from directoryInfo.
What i wanted to accomplish is to convert the string value to a date value for making comparison.

The folder name is sample like this C:\FOLD\20111120
and properly another folder path is like this 
C:\FOLD\20111021

20111120 is actually a date format. I am trying to convert it into date format to made some comparison decide to deleting the whole directory or not.

I think i shall paste my code here

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(_FolderPath);

foreach (DirectoryInfo f in dir.GetDirectories())
{
     String folderName = f.ToString();
     DateTime ConDt = Convert.ToDateTime(folderName);
     Console.WriteLine(ConDt);
     Console.WriteLine(ConDt.GetType());
   //Console.WriteLine(folderName.GetType());
   //Console.WriteLine(f.GetType());
}
```

I tried with Convert.toDatetime() and i get error that unable to made the converstion.How can i do so with this?

Comment: This might techically be a duplicate, but it's more clearly what I needed. +1

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You should *have to* use `DateTime.TryParseExact`.

```
var newDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20111120", 
                                  "yyyyMMdd", 
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

OR

```
string str = "20111021";
string[] format = {"yyyyMMdd"};
DateTime date;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, 
                           format, 
                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
                           out date))
{
     //valid
}
```

Comment: +1, but you don't need to pass an array if you're only using a single format string with `TryParseExact`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx

Comment: Just a quick note, if you ever need to support multiple date formats, the array is useful:
`string[] format = {"yyyyMMdd", "yyyy-MM-dd"};`