# How can I get my YYYYMMDD value to convert to DateTime?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

This should not be seen as a duplicate question, because I tried answers given elsewhere, and it's still not working.

For example, with this:

```
qr.DateToGenerate = DateTime.ParseExact(crvArray[2], "yyyyMMdd",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

...which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053887/convert-20121004-yyyymmdd-to-a-valid-date-time), where the value of `crvArray[2]` is "20161201", I get:

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
       at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style) . . .
```

And with the following code, which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206827/convert-yyyymmdd-string-date-to-a-datetime-value), the "Try" returns false and the assignment is not made.

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(crvArray[2],
               format,
               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
               System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
               out date))
{
    qr.DateToGenerate = date;
}
```

At what angle do I need to launch myself through the hoop?

### UPDATE

This (passing a literal string) works:

```
qr.DateToGenerate = DateTime.ParseExact("20161201", "yyyyMMdd", null, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

...but is not workable, of course.

This, though, does not:

```
private static QueuedReportsNew ConvertCRVRecordToQueuedReport(string _qrRecord)
{
    QueuedReportsNew qr = new QueuedReportsNew();
    string[] crvArray = _qrRecord.Split(',');
    . . .
    String dateToGen = crvArray[2];
    . . .
    qr.DateToGenerate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateToGen, "yyyyMMdd", null, DateTimeStyles.None);
    . . .
```

...even though the value of `crvArray[2]` is "20170105"

?!?

Comment: Are you sure that `crvArray[2]` has a valid date string?  [It works fine for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YX8Vsh).

Comment: Are you parsing a lot of rows? Some rows might have columns where the date string is empty or null.

Comment: Yes - the value of crvArray[2] is "20170105"

Comment: Call `ToCharArray()` on your `dateToGen` string and see if there are some extra non-printing characters in there.  (In the debugger Watch window, enter `"20170105".ToCharArray()` and also `dateToGen.ToCharArray()` and look for differences)

Comment: Could you post what _qrRecord looks like when the error is thrown?

Comment: @jgauffin: All the rows have values; most importantly, this one (the first one) does.

Comment: @ChrisBerger: Cafe Zupas, 6, 20170105, 20161127, 20161231

Comment: call .Trim() before you pass it into ParseExact

Comment: Create a [MCVE]. Really do a File|NewProject and demonstrate the problem in 2 or 3 lines before posting. Because ParseExact() is fine, your data or assumptions are not.

Comment: Yep, Trim() was the missing link.

Comment: Just about to post the same thing... =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, and I am willing to bet that crvArray[2] does *not* contain exactly `20170105`.

My guess would be that there's a non-printable character (for example, a space) somewhere. If that is the case, trimming your string (`crvArray[2].Trim()`) will fix that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Below method adds / sign after 4 and 2 chracters.returning value can be converted to DateTime

```
public string AddSignToDate(string date)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < date.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 4)
            {
                sb.Append("/" + date[i]);
            }
            else if (i == 6)
            {
                sb.Append("/" + date[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(date[i]);
            }                
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```