# Converting string "7.30" to time format hh:mm

Tags: c#, string, datetime, converters

I want to convert string to datetime or timespan. my string like this "7.30",i need to get difference in two times in c#. i tried many ways but problem didn't solved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to DateTime in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592653/convert-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4):

Does the `date` portion matter? Anyway, if you truly only need to convert that to a time and don't care about the date portion, you could do like this:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string inVal = "7.30";
        var x = DateTime.ParseExact(inVal, "H.mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Output:

> 6/16/2021 7:30:00 AM

Also, you should review Microsoft's custom date and time formats to ensure you have the best one for your use case:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 1):

Recommended to use [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-5.0) for DateTime conversion by specifying the DateTime string pattern, [Culture Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider?view=net-5.0), and [DateTimeStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimestyles?view=net-5.0).

This will help you to determine whether the parsed string is matched with the DateTime string pattern to be converted. Next, you can implement your custom logic for handling the wrong conversion.

Based on your provided DateTime string, I assume it is in this pattern (24 hours based):

```
H.mm
```

The solution should be as below:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime dateTime;
        bool isValidDateTime = DateTime.TryParseExact("7.30", "H.mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
        
        if (!isValidDateTime)
        {
            // TO-DO Handling for wrong time format
            return;
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("hh:mm"));
    }
}
```